# LinearOptimization duality

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I'm solving a linear program using LinearOptimization. I'm curious why "DualityGap" does not return zero (as described in the docs). Here's the code:

```
yb1 = 10;
yb2 = 10;
pi1 = 10/9;
pi2 = 10/9;
pi3 = 12/10;
LinearOptimization[
 -x1 - x2, {
  yb2 == x1 + x3, yb1 + y3 == x2,
  yb1 <= pi1 x1, yb2 <= pi2 x2, y3 <= pi3 x3,
  x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, x3 >= 0, y3 >= 0
  }, {x1, x2, x3, y3}, {"PrimalMinimumValue", "DualMaximumValue", 
  "DualMaximizer", "DualityGap"}]
```

The result is:

```
{-(101/5), -20, {{1/5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {6/5, 1}}, -(1/5)}
```

I've also described the dual (manually) and solved it using LinearOptimization, and its value coincides with the primal value, as expected.

Could this be a bug, or am I not seeing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce it. The output in 12.3 on Windows 10 Pro is `{-(101/5), -(101/5), {{9/50, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {6/5, 1}}, 0}`.

Comment: I also see the same result as @user64494.  (12.3 on Linux).  Perhaps you should try with a fresh kernel.  (E.g. `Quit[]` first)

Comment: Interesting! Just rebooted the kernel and it didn't make any difference. I have version 12.0.0.0. Maybe it is a bug that is now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I reproduced the OP result in 12.2, Windows 10

Comment: I reproduced it, too! (version 12.0 for macos)

Comment: Installed 12.3 and the bug is gone! Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

According to the above replies of other users, it seems the cause is a bug in Mathematica < 12.3. Running the above script in 12.3 works as expected, resulting in a duality gap of zero.